# add existing document field to aggregate output

Tags: mongodb

A MongoDB collection contains a number of documents with the following props:

```
{
  name: <value>
  timestamp: <value>,
  price: <value>
}
```

`timestamp`s aren't unique and I want to sum the `price` values found for each individual `timestamp`:

```
const entries = await Subscription
  .aggregate([
    { $match: { timestamp: parseInt(req.params.timestamp, 10) } },
    { $group: { _id: null, sum: { $sum: "$price" } } },
    { $project: {
      _id: false,
      sum: true
    }},
    { $limit: parseInt(req.params.limit, 10) }
  ])
```

How do I add the individual `timestamp` to the query output? Tried

```
{ $project: {
  _id: false,
  sum: true,
  timestamp: { $literal: parseInt(req.params.timestamp, 10) }
}}
```

But it looks to me like adding a field to the output when the field is present in the document.

Comment: (1) _"timestamps aren't unique and I want to sum the price values found for each individual timestamp"_: You want to _group on timestamp_ and _sum the price_. This will give the totals for each timestamp. Is this what you are looking for? (2) After grouping you can only use the outputs from the grouping in projection.

Comment: (1) Yes, first I want to sum all `price` values for an individual `timestamp`. Do I not need `$match`? (2) That much I figured hence the use of `$literal`. Are there better ways to include the value of `timestamp` to the query output? Do I need a different query?

Comment: Try running 1st and 2nd stages in your query (only), and see the result. The grouping should be on timestamp, not the null. Don't use the other stages, for now. See this example: [group by example](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html#calculate-count-sum-and-average).

Comment: It's not completely clear which question you are asking. You either want to simply "group by timestamp" which is just `{ "$group": { "_id": "$timestamp", "sum": { "$sum
": "$price" } } }`, OR the `timestamp` values themselves require some sort of "grouping" within intervals of whatever period. Both marked duplicates would appear to apply in either case, and "by interval" if only for understanding the principle.

Comment: Out of 300k entries there are 52 unique `timestamp`s. I need to sum up the `price` found for each unique `timestamp` and return the sum. And I also want to add the unique `timestamp` for which the sum is calculated to the query output. To display the timestamp/sum graph on the frontend page.